# Kotlin flatmap to unpack List of data class

Tags: kotlin, flatten, tornadofx

Given a list of 2D co-ordinates *which are a data class*

```
data class Point(val x: Int, val y:Int)
val points: List<Point>
```

and a TornadoFX (JavaFX in Kotlin) method which takes a flattened array of [x,y,x2,y2...]:

```
polyline(vararg points: kotlin.Number)
```

I just wrote the following and came away feeling this can't be all there is

```
fun List<Point>.asPolyline() = this.flatMap { p -> listOf(p.component1(), p.component2()) }

polyline(*points.asPolyline().toTypedArray())
```

Is there no way to expand the data class (similar to how the `Array` is spread with that `*`) or simply a better way to make this conversion?

Comment: I saw on the Kotlin forum someone asking about whether there could be an `fun <T> Iterable<Pair<T, T>>.flatten()`, and a team member responded that it was too niche to put in the standard library, because Pairs don't usually have common types. I think the same argument would be even stronger against data classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with minimal allocations:

```
fun List<Point>.toFlatArray() = 
    Array(size * 2) { with (this[it / 2]) { if (it % 2 == 0) x else y } }
```

Comment: Feels like a code-golf challenge winner (`this` and `it` and an implicit `with` subject _and_ an implicit extension-function subject all in the same one liner?) but, as the shortest path to the end goal, I'll take it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a materially different way to do this, but I think if we use a `fold` and a `MutableList`, it can be done without a `List` allocation for each `Point`:

```
fun List<Point>.asPolyline(): List<Number> = this.fold(mutableListOf()) { next, carry -> 
    next.apply {
        this.add(carry.x)
        this.add(carry.y)
    }
}
```